# Is There a Way to clone a B2C User Flow?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We're in the process of implementing AD B2C as our sso and will have to go through multiple versions of user flows during testing. They will be used for different environments and some in parallel in testing so we won't be able simply change existing versions. We'd like to establish a base flow for our sign in and our multiple sign ups as starting points that we could then clone when we create a new version. Is there any way to clone an existing User Flow either directly or by download/upload to a new flow? I know we could do something similar with custom policies but we've made the decision to stick with user flows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**User flows cannot be cloned as user flows, but you can download their source code and clone them as [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview#custom-policies).** User flows are custom policies anyways. You can download their source code from the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) as shown in the following picture.

[image]

You can opt to append the base policies code to the user flow code using the following API call. **Please keep in mind this API is not publicly supported and only provided AS IS**:

`GET https://main.b2cadmin.ext.azure.com/api/trustframework/GetAsXml?sendAsAttachment=true&tenantId=<TENANT NAME>.onmicrosoft.com&policyId=<USER FLOW ID>&getBasePolicies=true`

You will need an access token for scope `https://management.core.windows.net/user_impersonation`



Let me know if you need additional help!

Comment: Sorry for down voting but this answer does not answer the question, yes we can download the xml, bot how can we use it to create second user flow with different name and different api connectors?

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer, api connectors should be available in the base policies.

Comment: I have tried to upload a xml for user flow as custom policy through the azure portal and it has failed with very long error, that I could not extract from the ui. It was some thing abut inheritance. What am I missing here ? So user flow can be used as custom policy in principle but there is something wrong with my one ?

Comment: Ensure you're including the base policy: `https://main.b2cadmin.ext.azure.com/api/trustframework/GetAsXml?sendAsAttachment=true&tenantId=<TENANT NAME>.onmicrosoft.com&policyId=<USER FLOW ID>&getBasePolicies=true` or share the detailed error. You can get the full details using the browser console.

Comment: i have a cusompolicy and have a application in appregister, i want to connect thet application into custom policy, Currently i created two(using the documentation), but it think i dont need two app. How can i integrate the existing one to my custom policy?